# Passing in several hard coded arrays into (click) angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a button that takes is several hardcoded array. I am not using `*ngFor`

```
<button type="submit" (click)="search(checkBox[0],checkBox[1],checkBox[2],checkBox[3],checkBox[4],checkBox[5])" class="btn btn-default btn-md left-button">Search</button>
```

In my component it will only check `checkbox[0]` but none of the rest.

```
public search(ssn,userId,lastName,office,role) {

        if(ssn.checked == true){
            console.log("What is checked: "+ssn.name+" input: "+this.ssn);
            this.user = this._searchService.getUserBySSN(this.ssn);
        }
        else if(userId.checked == true){
            console.log("What is checked: "+userId.name+" input: "+this.userId);
            this.user = this._searchService.getUserById(this.userId);
        }
        else if(lastName.checked == true){
            console.log("What is checked: "+lastName.name+" input: "+this.lastName);
            this.user = this._searchService.getUserByLastName(this.lastName);
        }
        else if(office.checked == true){
            console.log("What is checked: "+office.name+" input: "+this.office);
            this.user = this._searchService.getUserByOffice(this.office);
        }
        else if(role.checked == true){
            console.log("What is checked: "+role.name+" input: "+this.role);
            this.user = this._searchService.getUserByRole(this.role);
        }

    }
```

html I have 6 checkboxes done like so:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 box-content right">
                        <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="checkbox" name="lastName" (change)="checkBox[1].checked=!checkBox[1].checked">
        </span>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
          <label>{{checkBox[1].label}}</label>
        </span>
                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lastName" name="lastNameTest" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Maybe because `ssn.checked` is true, and you used `else if`.

Comment: @JBNizet I had `if` for all of them and samething

Comment: How do you know that "it will only check checkbox[0]". What does that mean?

Comment: @JBNizet In the if statements only when I check `ssn` will I get output in the console. However all the other simply do nothing.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example, in a plunkr, reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet this is very weird but if I select SSN and select userId they both print in the console. HOWEVER if I skip the order and go `ssn` than `office` just `ssn` prints.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in those elements one at a time, you would be better off passing in the array object and checking it there.

Try this:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="search(checkBox)" class="btn btn-default btn-md left-button">Search</button>
```

Then your search method becomes:

```
public search(checkBoxArray: []){
    //Assign local variables here
    //Such as let ssn = checkBoxArray[0];
}
```

If it were possible for checkBox to instead be an object with key/value pairs, that would be easier to access.  All of this being said, if you pass in that array, you can console.log the whole array and see what is actually defined at that point in time.

Comment: `search(checkBoxArray: []){` says `A tuple element cannot be empty`AND ` ,`let ssn = checkboxArray[0];` fails when I try to check it here `if(ssn.checked == true){` saying `property checked does not exist type never`

Thank you for your efforts

Comment: If you have a better solution by all means share, This is say two messing with this page.

Comment: I think you want to architect this differently -- you should maintain the state of those checkboxes in your component, then just run a search method on that array when the button is clicked (without passing it in.)

Comment: That being said, I may have the TS declaration wrong -- it probably wants a type on the array.  Remove the type from the parameter and console log the checkBoxArray to see what it contains.

Comment: I took off the `: [ ]` and the same thing is happening.

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to maintain the checkboxes state and only allow them to select one at a time.

Comment: I would reconsider your implementation -- use ngModel on each of the checkboxes and link them to variables in an array in your component.  Then use a `some` on that array to see if any are checked to set the `disabled` attribute of the boxes.